# why doesn't it recognize the command and can't open the file when installing modules and packages with pip?

Tags: python, pip, failed-installation

ON WINDOWS, when trying to install packages or modules for Python 3.7. Eg.

When using the "pip install beautifulsoup4" command on cmd it just says:

> ""pip" isn't recognized as an internal or external command, program or executable batch file."

or

> pyhton.exe: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] no such file or directory

I use jupyter notebook and when ive been able to run any instalation instead of showing the complete and correct instalation always shows Warning messages saying about it working with TLS or SSL but the SSL is not installed or somethign like so.

I'm checking  if the moduls are getting installed with a little code

```
try:
    import numpy
except ImportError:
    print("Module not installed")
```

aparently numpy it does is installed but others are not getting installed

When using the "try" code i hope not to get the message and be able to use the modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't add Python to your Windows Path.

Here it is well explained how it works: (https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/) :)

Comment: Thanks i kinda solved the problem i'm now able to install new packages, although the command prompt still showing me a warning message everytime i install something:
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

I already tried to update it but it doesnt work it still says that "python" is not a command, it does accepts "py" though, but at the moment to make the upgrading it kinda seems like tha path change didnt had effect or so, it shows several paths and:
"no such option: -u"

Comment: Hey, I can't tell why upgrading isn't working for you in the terminal... If you are able to install packages, upgrading should be working too.... As a "hotfix" I would recommend you to download the latest version from the official [Python Website](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and launch the installation. Since you already have Python installed you will see a "Upgrade Now" - Button.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Even though python installed on Windows, it may be not pointing python path correctly.

Please ensure there is path for python in System environment.

Start -> type system environment -> Edit system environment -> System variables -> Path -> Please make sure you have path added for python -> Ok(Save).

And restart command prompt and run it again.

in command prompt,

```
py --version
```

or
    python3 --version
This should be tell you the version of python

Also

```
pip --version
```

This should be work too.